# Как получить названия словарей из текстового файла, значения ключей которых удовлетворяют условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл .txt , который содержит множество подобных строк:

```
Ivanon = {'math':4, 'english':4, 'physic':4, 'chemistry':4, 'biology':4}
Netfullin = {'math':5, 'english':4, 'physic':4, 'chemistry':5, 'biology':4}
Pasternak = {'math':5, 'english':4, 'physic':3, 'chemistry':5, 'biology':4}
Lenina = {'math':5, 'english':5, 'physic':5, 'chemistry':5, 'biology':5}
```

Каким способом можно распечатать названия этих словарей (фамилии), значения которых будут, например, все 5 ?

Comment: Данные в файле именно в таком виде? без кавычек?

Comment: с кавычками, неверно перепечатал, извиняюсь. Поправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный файл:

```
Ivanon = {'math':4, 'english':4, 'physic':4, 'chemistry':4, 'biology':4}
Doe = {'math':5, 'english':5, 'physic':5, 'chemistry':5, 'biology':5}
Mustermann = {'math':5, 'english':5, 'physic':5}
Dvoechnikov = {'math':3, 'english':3, 'physic':3, 'chemistry':3, 'biology':3}
```

**UPDATE:** это почти обычный YAML файл (если заменить знаки равно на двоеточия), поэтому его можно прочитать в словарь гораздо легче:

```
import yaml

with open(filename) as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f.read().replace('=',':'))
```

Результат:

```
In [94]: data
Out[94]:
{'Doe': {'biology': 5, 'chemistry': 5, 'english': 5, 'math': 5, 'physic': 5},
 'Dvoechnikov': {'biology': 3,
  'chemistry': 3,
  'english': 3,
  'math': 3,
  'physic': 3},
 'Ivanon': {'biology': 4,
  'chemistry': 4,
  'english': 4,
  'math': 4,
  'physic': 4},
 'Mustermann': {'english': 5, 'math': 5, 'physic': 5}}
```

---

**Старый ответ:**

Можно разбить строки на две части: Имя и словарь (в виде строки) с оценками при помощи простого регулярного выражения (`'\s*=\s*'`), а потом "спарсить" словарь (строку) в словарь используя [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

После этого сформировать список словарей вида:

```
[{'Name1':{'subj1':note, 'subj2':note, ...}, 
 {'Name2':{'subj1':note, 'subj2':note, ...}]
```

Далее можем искать по данному списку словарей.

Пример:

```
import re
import ast

def parse_line(line):
    name,rest = re.split('\s*=\s*', line)
    d = ast.literal_eval(rest)
    return {name:d}

filename = r'C:\Temp\.data\774534.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    data = [parse_line(line) for line in f]

#best_ones =  [n for x in data for n,d in x.items() if all(val == 5 for val in d.values())]        
best_ones = [n for x in data for n,d in x.items() if sum(d.values()) == 5*len(d)]
print(best_ones)
```

Результат:

```
['Doe', 'Mustermann']
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример. Сразу скажу, что он сложен для моего понимания и мне еще во многих моментах вашего кода предстоит разобраться. Однако, изменив только путь к файлу для тестирования решения - выходит ошибка:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
  File "C:\Python\lib\ast.py", line 65, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "C:\Python\lib\ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x064E9930>
Сделал ли я что-то не так?

Comment: не все строки ошибки поместились в комментарий

Comment: @badordos, похоже, что в вашем реальном файле данные в фигурных скобках не соответствуют словарю... Вы можете привести в вопросе несколько реальных строк, изменив только имена/фамилии?

Comment: я внимательно просмотрел файл и там действительно была ошибка в написании, теперь все работает правильно. Большое спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Если конфиг у вас в Питон-формате задан (как в вопросе), вы можете [импортировать файл как Питон модуль](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19009932/4279) и получить имя словаря по указанному критерию:

```
import inspect

module = module_from_file('config.txt')
for name, _ in inspect.getmembers(module, lambda o: isinstance(o, dict)
                                  and all(v == 5 for v in o.values())):
    print(name)
```

где `importlib` используется, чтобы файл по указанному пути загрузить как модуль:

```
import importlib.util

def module_from_file(path, module_name='<module>'):
    loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(module_name, path)
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

Лучше использовать `.py` расширения для файлов с Питон-кодом и положить в [место, доступное для импорта (`sys.path`)](http://www.diveintopython3.net/your-first-python-program.html#importsearchpath) как это сделано с [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/), тогда вы сможете к примеру просто `from myapp import config` использовать, чтобы модуль получить.

Если в вашем случае не нужна поддержка произвольного Питон-кода, тогда лучше использовать [более декларативные языки для конфигурации](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch08s01.html), к примеру, json, toml. Не изобретайте свои форматы и со своими парсерами, собранными на коленке -- это затрудняет как редактирование файлов (каждому человеку нужно новый формат учить), это поощряет баги. К примеру, наивная замена `.replace('=',':')` в [@MaxU ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774542/23044) сломается на первой же строке в словаре, которая `'='` содержит -- и даже хуже: этот код может молча испортить данные.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if all([raiting[-1] == '5' for raiting in line[line.index('{') + 1:line.index('}')].split(', ')]):
            print(line[:line.index('=')].strip())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Ваш пример так же выдает правильные фамилии, но в конце выдает ошибку "File "...", line 8, in <module>
    if all([raiting[-1] == '5' for raiting in line[line.index('{') + 1:line.index('}')].split(', ')]):
ValueError: substring not found"

Comment: в конце файла был косяк на моей стороне. Большое спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
[surname for (surname, _dict) in (line.split('=', 1) for line in filter(str.strip, open('file.txt'))) if all((val == 5) for val in eval(_dict).values())]
```

Comment: А если какой-нибудь шутник запишет в файл: `Killer = import shutil;

shutil.rmtree("/")` ;-)